# Can I build a mobile web site that has access to the iPhone camera?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, camera, webkit

Does webkit have access to the camera API on the iPhone?  What about other phones?  I want to build a mobile website that enables users to click on a button that opens the camera, ask if you want to take a new picture or user an existing one (assume the former), take a picture, confirm the picture is good, then be routed back to web site where the new picture is uploaded.  is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you access the iPhone camera from Mobile Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607067/can-you-access-the-iphone-camera-from-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 1):

At this time, this is not possible. You can, however, use a toolkit such as PhoneGap to acheive this.