# iPhone camera access for webapp

Tags: ios, safari, camera

Is there a way for a web app to access the native iPhone camera and photos? I do not want to use PhoneGap or iOS SDK. From this stackoverflow question a year back, it looks like iPhone camera is not available through Mobile Safari: [Can you access the iPhone camera from Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607067/can-you-access-the-iphone-camera-from-mobile-safari) . Is it still the case?

If I can't access camera app in a webapp what are my best options?

Comment: Since iOS 6 this is possible, see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14295860/778675

Comment: Try this, it works on iPhone Safari
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51501294/5737750

Comment: Try is, it worked on iPhone Safari browser https://stackoverflow.com/a/51501294/5737750

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the iPhone app Picup. From my webapp, I called the Picup iPhone app which took the photos and sent to my Rails server.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot access the camera API from a web app.