# How to access iphone camera from server-side web page?

Tags: iphone, camera

How to access iphone camera from webapp(server-side web)? (ex asp,php,jsp)

Comment: I guess there is no way to access local resources of iPhone eg Camera, Files  using Web.So why Native App comes in picture to access local resources.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for code running on a server to access an iPhone's camera.
It's not even possible for client-side web-app code (Javascript, HTML, CSS) to access the camera.

You'll need to write a full native app to be able to work with the camera. If you'd still like to be able to use web-technologies to do this, have a look at PhoneGap: http://phonegap.com/

PhoneGap makes it easier to write an app that loads a web page, but allows for access to device native APIs. Building the user interface will be more difficult though.

Comment: This answer is outdated and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to  access camera in iOS

First, in HTML body use video tag as below

```
<video id="video" class="video" height="400" width="400" playsinline autoplay muted loop></video>
```

this will ask permission to access the camera

Then in JavaScript, by using video element, display the video on the video tag

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
    .then(function(s) {
    stream = s;
    video.srcObject = s;
    video.play();
  })
```