# iPhone (Safari or Chrome) browser image capture (Take Photo or Video) doens't allow multiple files for FileUpload - Asp.net

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone

I've below code in asp.net ascx file.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="selectedFiles" runat="server" onchange="ShowImagePreview(this);" CssClass="inputhidden" AllowMultiple="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

There is some javascript code in ShowImagePrivew which preview the image on the page. The problem is every time we capture the image in iPhone, i'm getting the same name of the file while in Android Phones it is different on each image capture.

1) In order to test open the link in iPhone and Android.    http://aspuploader.com/demo/form-multiplefiles.asp
2) Click on Select Multiple files and select Take Photo
3) Take snapshot and upload that file
4) Again try to upload one more image

Result:
iPhone - It replace the old file. It uses image.jpg as temporary file name.
Android - It upload another file as well. It appends datetime as well.

Expected output: iPhone also should be able to upload multiple images.

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search I believe that it is not possible as it is default iPhone Behavior.
Also Refer: [Mobile Safari Multiple Upload with Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392689/mobile-safari-multiple-upload-with-camera)