# How to detect Camera in IPhone with Safari 10 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Need quick help if anyone knows how we can detect camera in IPhone with Safari 10 browser in WebApplication using javascript.
I saw some forums which mentioned to use geusermedia WebRTC APIs but Safari 10 does not support it?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607067/can-you-access-the-iphone-camera-from-mobile-safari

Comment: Yeah I tried it. Infact we are using the same solution (<input type="file" capture ... />) which is given in this forum. But we don't want to allow user to open file chooser if camera is not available or blocked by user in Safari 10 with mobile so for that purpose we are looking for a code which can be used. We used getUserMedia to detect the camera but this solution will never work with Safari 10.