# Open Camera APP from Safari

Tags: ios, safari, camera

How can I open the apple's app Camera from a link in safari ?

Something like :

```
<a href='apple:camera'>Open camera APP</a>
```

it's about using the qrcode.

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607067/can-you-access-the-iphone-camera-from-mobile-safari

Comment: No its not. I am asking about opening app, not using it. I dont want to take a picture and use it in the file upload. Please dont lose your time answering things like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can achieve this.
Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Nonetheless, can you you try the following solution (I think it opens the gallery not photo app)?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
window.location = "photos-redirect://";
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
window.location = "photos://";
</script>
```

Comment: How do we get an image back from this though...